# Given $0\leq \beta\leq \tau\leq 1$, prove $e^\beta - 1\leq (1+\tau)\beta$ and $1-e^{-\beta}\geq (1-\frac{\tau}{2})\beta$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How to prove 
$$e^\beta -1 \leq (1+\tau)\beta$$ and
$$1-e^{-\beta}\geq (1-\frac{\tau}{2})\beta$$
, provided that $0\leq \beta\leq \tau\leq 1$.
Many thanks!

Comment: This is obviously equivalent to $e^{\beta} \leq 1+\beta+\beta^{2}$ for $0 \leq \beta \leq 1$. Can you handle this?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give me more hints?

Comment: @rossini Do not hesitate to ask for any clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Kavi Rama Murthy in the comments, for the first one, we have that

$$e^x\le 1+x+ x^2$$

and then

$$e^\beta \leq 1+\beta+\beta^2 \implies e^\beta-1 \leq (1+\beta)\beta\le (1+\tau)\beta$$

For the second one, we have that

$$e^{-x}\le 1-x+\frac12 x^2$$

and then

$$e^{-\beta} \leq 1-\beta+\frac12\beta^2 \implies 1-e^\beta \geq \left(1-\frac12\beta\right)\beta \ge \left(1-\frac12\tau \right)\beta$$

To prove $e^x\le 1+x+ x^2$ let consider $f(x)=e^x-1-x-x^2\le0,\, x\in[0,1]$ then

- $f(0)=0$
- $g(x)=f'(x)=e^x-1-2x  \le 0$

indeed

- $g(0)=0$
- $g(1)=-2$
- $g'(x)=e^x-2=0 \implies x=\ln 2$ which is a minimum

therefore the inequality holds.

To prove $e^{-x}\le 1-x+\frac12 x^2$ let consider $f(x)=e^{-x}- 1+x-\frac12 x^2 \le0,\, x\in[0,1]$ then

- $f(0)=0$
- $g(x)=f'(x)=-e^{-x}+1-x  \le 0$

indeed

- $g(0)=0$
- $g(1)=-\frac1e$
- $g'(x)=e^{-x}-1\le 0 $

therefore the inequality holds.

Comment: Something wrong? Please let me know in order to fix that!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $$f(\beta)=\ln(1+(1+\tau)\beta)-\beta$$ and use calculus

Comment: Thanks but how?

Comment: Compute the first derivative with respect to $\beta$

Comment: Thanks, I see. $f'(\beta)=\frac{1+\tau}{1+(1+t)\beta} - 1$, form which we know that $f(\beta)$ acheives its maximum value at $1-\frac{1}{1+\tau}$.  As well, we can get that $\min_{0\leq \beta\leq \tau\leq 1}f(\beta)\geq \min(f(0), f(1))=0$